# MySQL/Percona 5.6: INSERT INTO a table after a table is ALTERed

Tags: mysql, sql, database, percona

I have recently installed a new computer with Percona Server 5.6 instead of MySQL 5.6, and using InnoDB/XtraDB mostly, FWIW. The database I'm working on is merely a testing ground, but I have 1 issue: after I add a column to a table (or even remove one), I usually forget to INSERT or otherwise change another table's data, which keeps track of what column names are in which table; each table has ASCII name along with a number, and this number is the only difference between table names for simplicity. **So, is there a way to auto-update the "relation" table so that the column name and table's number are added or changed, instead of using a cronjob ?**

Now that I think, I could DROP that table and use information_schema instead ...

***EDIT 0:*** Don't let the above realization stop you; it's just good to know if this is possible before going for a possible other way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, relying on the 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS' may be best.

Unfortunately mysql does not support DDL TRIGGER events, as this would be what you are looking for.

triggers allow you to perform many SQL and procedural operations before insertion, update or deletion of rows in a specific table. However to the best of my knowledge - and I would be stoked if I were wrong - you cant set TRIGGER events on DDL statements like ALTER and DROP TABLE...

However still take the time to learn about triggers - they save a lot of time by eliminating the need for cronjobs and external updates for things like aggregate values.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: It may however be possible to make it work in reverse. ie in your pseudo-info schema table that you realized may be redundant - ON INSERT to that tbl.alter the other table. You cant use this on information schema still as those are actually views.